# Problem with latex2rtf. Unknown commands. How to solve it?

Tags: amsmath, conversion, msword, word-to-latex

I'm having some difficulties to convert a TeX document into an MS-Word readable one.

I'm trying to use `latex2rtf` but I had this output ([pastebin](http://pastebin.com/puWfgi0T)).

Looks like the main problem is some unrecognized packages, like [amsmath](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath).

Several usual commands appears as unknown:

```
main.tex:11  Package/option 'epsfig' unknown.
main.tex:11  Package/option 'psfrag' unknown.
main.tex:12  Package/option 'multirow' unknown.
main.tex:12  Package/option 'colortbl' unknown.
main.tex:12  Package/option 'array' unknown.
main.tex:13  Package/option 'subfig' unknown.
main.tex:69  Unknown command '\mathbb'
...
```

Please take a look in [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/puWfgi0T) to see all the output and problems.

How can I solve this? How can I convert a compilable `.tex` file into an MS-Word file with all the things working fine?

I have tried to use `tex2word` on Windows, but while the file compiles normally in TeXStudio, when I open it using `tex2word` I have an infinite loop.

Opening the file with MS-Word, the unrecognized things appear like this:

[image: error]

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't see any solution so far. [According to its website](http://latex2rtf.sourceforge.net/), LaTeX2rtf is "intended to translate a LaTeX document *(precisely: the text and a limited subset of LaTeX tags)*" (emphasis mine). IMHO, it is almost impossible to find a tool with a proper one-to-one mapping. `:(`

Comment: @PauloCereda It is very bad =. Not all equations looks bad, some of them are correct, but these another ones and some other commands have a bad format.

Comment: Probably you could use some other tool to convert to html and import that into word.  Two ideas: `latex2html` and `pandoc`.

Comment: In general, I think the best conversion tool is [tex4ht](http://tug.org/tex4ht), but I've also had success with [tth](http://hutchinson.belmont.ma.us/tth/).  The former can produce an `.odt` (for OpenOffice or LibreOffice) or `.html` file (for example), while the latter produces `.html`; from there, one can convert to a MicroSoft format.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<sub>Converting my comment to an answer.</sub>

Unfortunately, I don't see any solution so far. [According to its website](http://latex2rtf.sourceforge.net/), `LaTeX2rtf` is "intended to translate a LaTeX document *(precisely: the text and a limited subset of LaTeX tags)* " (emphasis mine).

As others mentioned, you might try other tools such as [`pandoc`](http://code.google.com/p/pandoc/), but IMHO, it is almost impossible to find a tool with a proper one-to-one mapping. `:(`

Comment: I've had really good luck with pandoc and use that instead. For example, many times people say "rtf" when they really mean "MS Word compatible file" and pandoc can directly output .docx files.